# Using custom fonts; Is the pdf shown the same on all devices?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, embedding

I want to use some custom fonts (OpenType and TrueType) for my CV.

Will the font, or only glyphs got embedded into final PDF? And it will render correctly on other devices such as smartphones or very old PCs with old versions of Adobe Reader?

Not that I'm using `XeLaTex` to compile TeX.

Comment: i would trust only glyphs that are embedded in the pdf to be reliably displayed.  since the font information is embedded, it should work equally well on all devices with competent display software.  (conjecture, not tested.)

Comment: Only glyph outlines are embedded. Not the whole font, and not the various Open Type tables that appear in an actual font. Furthermore, TeX does not normally place the space character between words (there is a way to do that with pdflatex, but not lualatex, and probably not xetex). Thus, some PDF readers (including Acrobat Reader on a desktop) are incapable of accurately re-flowing text to fit a narrow screen. Other readers can guess the reflow. Doesn't matter whether your fonts are custom or not. If you have access to Adobe Acrobat Pro, post-process your CV and add accessibility tags.

Comment: What do you mean by `the font or only glyphs`? The viewer does not need the full font to render the PDF correctly. (Reflowing is a different issue as is copy-pasting, but this has nothing to do with what gets embedded in the PDF.) Your PDF will NOT render correctly unless ALL fonts are embedded, but subsetting is fine. You don't need the whole font embedded - just the glyphs used in the PDF.